# How to display xhtml page contents in pdf using JSF2 & iText only, pdf displays no data

Tags: pdf, jsf-2

My requirement:
click on 'Print' button in JSF2 and open a pdf file for printing with the data from the xhtml page.

The below code opens a blank pdf file with no data. I want pdf to display data from xhtml page (URL)

JSF code:
JSF has some fields to display data

```
<h:commandButton id="printButton" value="Print" actionListener="#{myBean.print}" />
```

MyBean.Java code:

```
 public void print()
 {
 ExternalContext externalContext =FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
 HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)externalContext.getResponse();     

 String url = request.getRequestURL();

 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
 document.open();
 document.add(new Paragraph(" Hello"));

 response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control",  "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + PDF_FILE_NAME + "\"");
 response.setContentLength(baos.size());
 ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

 baos.writeTo(out);
 out.flush();
 out.close();

 document.close();
 System.out.println("Done."); 
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The `baos` will only be filled when you call `document.close()`. So, basically, you're writing an empty `baos` to the response.

Replace that `baos` by `response.getOutputStream()` so that iText writes directly to the response instead of via an unnecessary circumvent.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
```

Don't forget to remove the following lines which have become superfluous:

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

---

Note that I'm only answering the described problem symptom based on the code provided so far. This all has absolutely nothing to do with "How to display xhtml page contents" and "display data from xhtml page (URL)" as you said there.